# Flutter null safety plugin_platform_interface

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, platform, dart-null-safety

I have this error,

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:plugin_platform_interface
```

the problem is I didn't use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/plugin_platform_interface) and I don't have it in the dependencies or lib, so how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

> Add this to your pubspec.yaml file and click/ run pub get.
> Then try to build again!

```
 plugin_platform_interface: ^2.1.2
```

Comment: i made new project with the same lib and dependencies and it's worked, i didn't need the  plugin_platform_interface: ^2.1.2
how to solve this problem without using the package in the old project ?